# Condition in the definition of the functions $E,$ $F$ and $G$ in Gauss's linear element formulas

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Working toward understanding [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)) on page 70 of [Eisenhart, Luther P. (2004), A Treatise on the Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces](https://archive.org/details/treatonthediffer00eiserich/page/n87) the following is stated:

A linear element on a parametrized surface $S$ of the form

$$\begin{align}
x=f_1(u,v)\\
y=f_2(u,v)\\
z=f_3(u,v)
\end{align}$$

on any curve will have equations of the form $\phi(u,v)=0$ will have linear elements of the curve given by

$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

where

$$\begin{align}
dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv\\
dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv\\
dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}dv\\
\end{align}$$

**the differentials $du,dv$  satisfying the condition $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}dv=0$$**

How can I see that this last line (this condition) makes sense or is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\phi(u,v)=0$, so the differential of $\phi$ must also be zero. The differential is
$$d\phi=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}dv.$$

Comment: That simple... All the elements in the equation are moved to the LHS in the formulation of the curve, leaving zero on the RHS, and hence any differential element will also be zero...